# How do I change the tables I use when my site has a lot of traffic?

Tags: mysql, server-load

Well, I have built a set of tables that run are meant to run with fewer joins, but I want to keep my normalized database around.  Is there a way to switch between them when my site has a lot of traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in order to simplify your queries, you might want to [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html)  which in turn can bundle some joins.

Comment: I guess I just liked your answer the best.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global that is incremented each time a page is accessed and resets to 0 de-incremented by 1 per minute per incrementation called '`pages_accessed_per_minute`'.

Create a function that takes two arguments, one the global mentioned above, and  the other the limit for your throttle: `throttleOn('pages_accessed_per_minute', '1000')`.

If the number of pages being accessed per minute increases beyond a certain point (1000 in this case), swap in the alternate php scripts which use the other databases.

```
if throttleOn('pages_accessed_per_minute', '1000') == true){
  include_once('dbAccess1.php');
}
else{
  include_once('dbAccess2.php');
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that I'm using include_once correctly, though.

I also discovered that most servers have a log symlinked to their users' home directories on shared hosts.  These logs can be monitored live with the `$tail -f` (command line).  It's better than polling because the server may become busy, and it's better to rely on hooks when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this "in production", but keep in mind that this can become critical very fast!

- Alter your tables by adding the additional columns you need.
- Populate the new columns (with a script, so that you can control how many rows are touched per time to make sure you do not generate to much load)
- Change your (website)-scripts using the new structure. Best way would be to update all scripts at the same time.
- Re-run your "populate-script" to ensure all rows are really in the new format
- Remove unneccessary columns/tables

Comment: Do you really mean to `alter` the table while it is being used in production?

Comment: No, I don't mean to `alter`.  The tables are already set up with the appropriate columns.  I populate all of the tables in-production.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there any way to switch between them?
A: Sure - just redirect to a different PHP page which does a different query of a different set of tables.

... however ...

Q: How are you going to keep the tables in synch?

Q: What mechanism is available to alert you that "your site has a lot of traffic"?

Comment: Q1 response: I am actually looking for the answer to Q3, so that I can do just that.  Q2 response: My tables won't always be in sync.  Using CRON to periodically migrate data from the normalized columns.  Q3 response: All that I have now are various trended content states.  I'd like to have something more definitive to throttle by, which is at the core of the question, as you suggest.